# Mongodb node doesn't sync with ReplicaSet after failure

Tags: database, mongodb, synchronization, replicaset

Cluster: 3 nodes (one failed)

Data: ~150GB

Oplog: about 24 hours

Each node have 4GB RAM

I have Mongodb cluster, which contains 3 mongodb nodes in the same ReplicaSet. The cluster is managed by OpsManager.

A few days ago, one of the nodes in the replicaset failed, there wasn't enough Oplog available to automatic sync with the replica.
I have tried to sync manually the node, by removing all his DBPath content and trigger inital sync (The full process was, stop the mms service, kill the mongod process, remove the data and start the mms service).

The node state was changed to 'STARTUP2' (initial sync). I was watching the dbpath data to track the sync process (using 'watch du -sh /var/lib/mongo'), the data grew fine, but then after about 80GB, the whole data has been removed (the command showed 100MB), and the sync was started over again. (Im aware that WiredTiger doesnt release the storage to the OS, and release it once in a while, but this drop looks to sharp).
This sync process happened many times (I let the sync run for 2 days).

I have also tried to start the sync from backup. I have used Snapshot from OpsManager (I have checked that there are enough oplog to sync from the snapshot). But once I started the mms service the entire data was removed.

I have also considerd to start from filesystem backup from another node in the ReplicaSet, but this process require Database lock, and therefore will cause problems with majority write concern.

Do you have any suggestions how to sync the node with the replicaset?

Thanks.

Comment: What about if you try to create a new replica set?

Comment: Identify what logs exist for each of the programs you mentioned (mongod, ops manager, etc.) and inspect them for clues.